# How to enable read-write access to the directory used by Azure function in C:\home\site\wwwroot?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an C# based HTTP trigger Azure function that downloads a zip file, extracts it, and reads a .txt file present in it. The directory used by the function is `C:\home\site\wwwroot`, which is only available for read, and I am not able to create or write a file to it. As a result, the function throws **FileNotFoundError **for .txt file.

I tried removing the ENV variable **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE**= 1 (When **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** is set to 1, it indicates that the application is running from a zip package file, and the contents of the package are read-only. Therefore, you cannot create or modify files in the wwwroot directory or any other directory that's part of the package) which apparently removed the Azure function altogether.

Is there any way to enable read-write access to this directory or any suggestion for an alternative approach to handle this issue?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about using storage? Blob or FileStorage?

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the drive where code is running from.  As @mdzieg says, upload the file to a Blob or FileStorage (which is what they are for) and process the file from there.

Comment: One more idea, you can try `Path.GetTempPath()` to create a temporary file in case you want it only to run command or sth. `path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".zip");`

Comment: Thanks @mdzieg @Neil for the suggestions.

@mdzieg I did tried the above `Path.GetTempPath()` approach but since I had to extract lot of zip files it runs out of space and throwed

**System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk. : 'C:\local\Temp\fileName.txt'**

I would explore more upon the suggestion you provided to use blob storage. Will update the thread

Comment: https://josef.codes/azure-storage-zip-multiple-files-using-azure-functions/

Answer (score 1):

You better use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` to store your downloaded file, extract and read it there...

Comment: I have added this reference `using System.IO`, so it won't cause any change the way I used it earlier.